# Android set date and time is not displaying in log cat

Tags: java, android, datetime

My Code

Used for Fetching date and time in Android-Java

```
try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
            String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
            final File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "SMOK_komunal");
            if (!path.exists()) {
                path.mkdir();
            }
            Log.e("path ", path.getAbsolutePath()+ " and "+currentDateandTime );

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat  -f " + path + File.separator + "dbo_logcat_" + currentDateandTime + ".txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

While logging the value .it doesn't display the date and time... can anyone help me?

Comment: did you get date and time in variable? or your only problem is date and time is not displaying in log?

Comment: @sugansoft a date and time is not displaying in log

Comment: Write  Log.e("currentDateandTime ",""+currentDateandTime ) ; for getting date and time

Comment: i have answered you.. if its works accept my answer

Comment: Probably you have an exception

Comment: @sugansoft in low android I don't have a time and date in logs

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin but I have logs but don't have a time and date in logs

Comment: Use debugger...

Answer (score 2):

```
 try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                final File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "SMOK_komunal");
                if (!path.exists()) {
                    path.mkdir();
                }
                Log.e("path ",""+path.getAbsolutePath());
                Log.e("Currentdateandtime",""+currentDateandTime );

                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat  -f " + path + File.separator + "dbo_logcat_" + currentDateandTime + ".txt");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Android :To get date and time

```
public String timezone          =   TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
```

If you are using Pure android you can follow above to get timezone

If you are using java you can follow the below code to print date and time
http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/current-date-time-in-java/ Refer this

if you are using android oncreate

use my code.. i got output for this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
//setContentView(R.layout.main); 

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime()); 

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime()); 
// formattedDate have current date/time 
Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


// Now we display formattedDate value in TextView 
TextView txtView = new TextView(this); 
txtView.setText("Current Date and Time : "+formattedDate); 
txtView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
txtView.setTextSize(20); 
setContentView(txtView); 
}
```

Comment: In pure android I don't have a date and time how I can display a time in pure android ?

Comment: pure android use the code and check you will get the value import java.util.TimeZone;

public String timezone          =   TimeZone.getDefault().getID();

Comment: also you can try with this String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

Comment: This is how look like my log line in file : E/set caption DI(32499): Lista Tras - data akt. 26-07-2017 Pojazd czajniczek

Comment: And I need a date and time in my log

Comment: Can you assign the value to textview and verify the answer instead displaying in log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150156/discussion-between-krzysztof-pokrywka-and-sugansoft).

Answer (score 0):

IF you mean time is not Logging out in your code, you haven't formatted for  **Time**. to show Time you have to format like this.

```
           SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                     "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                Log.e("TAG"," and "+currentDateandTime );
```

OR if you mean even your date is not logging out. make sure

> new Date();

is not returning null.  & if it's not null, try logging out

> Log.e("TAG"," and "+new Date() );

and see if it's showing an empty string. and proceed debugging accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should log after the execution of logcat command, like this:

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(                    
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        final File path = new 
        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "SMOK_komunal");

        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdir();
        }
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + path + File.separator 
        + "dbo_logcat_" + currentDateandTime + ".txt" + " *:E");

        Log.e("path ",""+path.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.e("Currentdateandtime",""+currentDateandTime );


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: I don't have in my file with logs a date and time on my logs line . I want to have date and time in each line